# NSDictionary within NSArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary

A quick question about NSArrays and NDictionarys.

I have and NSArray containing NSDictionarys.
The NSDictionary contain a date and a string.

What I would like to do is end up with an NSDictionary with keys dates and values arrays of strings that are on that date.

What would be the best way to do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSMutableDictionary *result = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
for (NSDictionary *dict in array) {
    NSDate *date = [dict objectForKey:@"dateKey"];
    NSString *string = [dict objectForKey:@"stringKey"];
    NSMutableArray *stringsWithDate = [result objectForKey:date];
    if (!stringsWithDate) {
        stringsWithDate = [NSMutableArray array];
        [result setObject:stringsWithDate forKey:date];
    }
    [stringsWithDate addObject:string];
}
```

Note that `NSDate` is not a "calendar date", so the same day with a different time will be considered as a distinct date in your result dictionary.

Comment: I've made sure all the NSDates are at 00:00 by using this             NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
            [cal setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];
            NSDateComponents *comp = [cal components:(NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSYearCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit) fromDate:tempDate];
            NSDate *dateToAdd = [cal dateFromComponents:comp];

Comment: should         [result setObject:stringsWithDate forKey:date];
be after the if statement, after doing that works perfectly, THANKKKS!

Comment: Actually it should work with the `[result setObject:...]` inside the if statement.

Answer (score 2):

As I do not see any reasonable motivation for doing this, let's call it code golf.

```
NSMutableArray *dates = [NSMutableArray array];
NSMutableArray *strings = [NSMutableArray array];

for (NSDictionary *dict in dictArray) {
    [dates addObject:[dict objectForKey:@"date"]];
    [strings addObject:[dict objectForKey:@"string"]];
}

NSArray *datesArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:dates];
NSArray *stringsArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:strings];
```